# regex help splitting a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split this string into an array

```
"Test One@,@10000@,@Test Two@,@10001"
```

Only keeping the words, the rest can go away. So I would end up with

```
[ "Test One", "Test Two" ]
```

The regex for this is escaping me. any help?

Answer (score 6):

If that's all you're doing, I would use split instead:

```
>>> "Test One@,@10000@,@Test Two@,@10001".split('@,@');
["Test One", "10000", "Test Two", "10001"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var string = "Test One@,@10000@,@Test Two@,@10001";

var array = string.match(/([a-z\s]+)/ig); // ["Test One", "Test Two"]
```

Comment: To gain a tiny bit of performance, consider removing the parentheses in the RegEx, like so:`var array = string.match(/[a-z\s]+/ig);`

Answer (score 1):

What about [`string.split(..)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method?

```
var split_array = "Test One@,@10000@,@Test Two@,@10001".split("@.@");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regex for this. You can use standard string functions. Building on **Leonard Challis**' answer (which returns all elements, not just the words), you can do something like this:

```
var myStrings = "Test One@,@10000@,@Test Two@,@10001".split('@,@');
var splitList = [];

var i = myStrings.length;
while(i--) {
    if(IsNaN(myStrings[i])) splitList.push(myStrings[i]);
}
```

`splitList` will now contain only the words, which is specifically what you asked for. Its contents would look like this:

```
["Test One", "Test Two"]
```

Which is what you requested.